# R Equivalent Of GetBytes() in C#

Tags: c#, r, character-encoding

I have a C# script that I want to re-create in R, but I'm having trouble finding the R code equivalent for a few functions.

Here is my C# code that I'd like to replicate in my R script:

```
var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
var keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(apiSecretKey);
var messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(stringToSign);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with C# but I would do that in R with charToRaw function.

Eg.

```
charToRaw("Hello world!")
 [1] 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21
```